# Can a GPU "forget" its subvendor?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card

I have an EVGA Geforce GTX 1060 which I overclocked heavily using Nvidia inspector.
I also set the power threshold to 70% to be a little easier on my PSU.

Now recently the GPU seems to ignore my power settings and also reports a different name in Nvidia inspector. It used to be listed there as "EVGA Geforce GTX 1060" but now it's called "Nvidia Geforce GTX 1060" it also states Nvidia as subvendor when it used to say EVGA there.
About ignoring the power settings: It used to draw around 70 - 75 W with my settings and now it draws around 100 W no matter what I set the power threshold to. Even if I go as low as 50%.

So my question is. Did something reset inside the card? Can it be that some component broke down? Could a BIOS flash on the card solve that issue?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you installed some customised drivers from the CD that came with the graphics card and that they have since been replace with the standard Nvidia drivers.

While vendors have the option of customising the branding of software the drivers themselves are usually direct from Nvidia.

It is entirely possible that the only change between EVGA and Nvidia drivers is that they altered the device description (that you will see in Device Manager) to say EVGA rather than Nvidia.

When the drivers get updated, either by Windows Update, by a Windows feature upgrade, by the Geforce Experience software or by you by manually visiting the Nvidia site, it would effectively wipe those minor "text only" customizations.

---

If they *had* customised the card specifically then I would expect it to be the VBIOS that tells the GPU what exactly to report itself to the system as. That your graphics card works tells me the VBIOS is likely fine.

Running [GPU-z](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) might tell you more about the card.

Comment: Windows 10 in particular can be VERY obnoxious. Replacing your drivers with the generic Microsoft WHQL driver for NVidia GPU's, without any warning at all. Often yo can't even tell from the WindowsUpdate logs that it did this.

Comment: @Tonny on top of that you loose all device installation history after feature updates so if you had a version that worked better for whatever reason then you have no way to find out what it even might have been.

Comment: Very insightful thanks!
But could this also cause the card to ignore my power settings? It used to draw way less power with literally the same settings. Now it draws power like I'd expect it to do on stock settings.

Comment: Additional info: I am indeed running windows 10 and I never installed the drivers from the CD as I don't have an optical drive. I just downloaded the latest Nvidia drivers and installed them

Comment: @Jeffrey curious. Could you run GPU-z and post a screenshot. Power settings being ignored could be a driver issue or needing an update to the tool you used, hard to say for sure.